# How can I target next or sibling element in jquery or css?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I have an issue trying to target the next element in a men.

Let's say we have this structure :

```
<ul>
 <li class="active">
    <a href=""><i class=""></i></a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href=""><i class=""></i></a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

My goal is to give an animation on every "i" or element that is next to the current active li.

I aslo need to change its color, or add a blink effect to help user understand that they can click on the element. The reason it's because it is an icon and maybe they don't see it...

**What I tried:**

I tried with +, ~ in css, and .next(), nextAll() etc in jquery..

**EDIT**:
The examples given below work well with the simple structure shown here, thank you very much for your help.

But with the bootstrap 4 tabs, the active class is in the  element so the structure becomes

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="" class="active"><i class=""></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class=""></i></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And with this new structure, whatever I try, I can't manage to change the color or animate the  that is after the active class... (the second li)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```css
li.active ~ li > a {
color:red;
}
li.active ~ li > a >i {
color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link active</a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or maybe this:

```css
li.active + li > a {
color:red;
}
li.active + li > a >i {
color:green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link active</a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
<li><a href=""><i class="">icon</i>link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you very much, it help me undestand, i'll try with this!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you use the selectors the wrong way?

Here is an actual [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdPvpb)

Css used is:

```
// Targets the next one to active
li.active + li a  {
}

// Targets next one and all after that, after active
li.active ~ li a {

}
```

Comment: thank you very much , yes i think i'm doing wrong..!  i'll try with your code

Answer (score 0):

[From CSS-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/):

> An adjacent sibling combinator selector allows you to select an element that is directly after another specific element.

```
p + p { font-size: smaller; }
// Selects all paragraphs that follow another paragraph
#title + ul { margin-top: 0; }
// Selects an unordered list that directly follows the element with ID title
```

Comment: thank you very  much i tried with + but no success..i'll try again!

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to target the child element(s) of li having class "active".

you can do it like this

```
li.active a {
    /*your style goes here*/
}
li.active i {
    /*your style goes here*/
}
```